# Get device motion from the past on iOS/WatchKit

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion

I want to let my device (iPhone/Watch) record the movements of the user. It seems Apple isn't providing a way to do this in "real-time". The only way I found is to use [CMSensorRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmsensorrecorder) to get "historical" data from the past. But this sensor recorder samples at 50 Hz, so there are ~50 samples per second. If you want to record the user's activity for e.g. two hours or more, then you have to process 50 * 60 * 60 * 2 = 360.000 samples. That's a real pain on the Apple Watch because of the processor.

I've seen apps on the AppStore which seem to use exactly this sensor recorder to do some analysis based on the movement data. Is there another way to get movement data from the past? Or to set the sample rate of the recorder? I have already put hours of work into my app, but I can't get the data processing fast enough. It's really slow ...